# How can I add the French trademark symbol (MC)?

Tags: html, css, tags, w3c, symbols

How can I add the French trademark symbol MC as like TM?
I have tried on below link. But there is only "M" unicode available.
http://unicodelookup.com/#7481/1

Comment: As a french (not working in this field and not willing to), I've never seen "MC", maybe seldomly "MD" and am quite used to see "TM" and "(R)", far more recognizable even if these are english acronyms. If you've been given a document with these symbols, well OK but if you're trying to translate every single symbol in french, maybe you shouldn't translate this one?

Answer (score 1):

You could use

`<sup style="font-size:7pt;">MC</sup>`

Which makes it look like a trade mark?

You can adjust the size whenever you want too!

[Example.](http://jsfiddle.net/6n3Zj/)